# /proc/slabinfo: Input/output error

Tags: xfs, linux

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and XFS (kernel 3.2.0-38-generic). Because XFS inode cache use too much memory, I want to limit the number of objects used to cache XFS inode.

According to the manual, I can limit the number by writing limit to /proc/slabinfo. But I cannot write to /proc/slabinfo even with superuser privileges.

```
$ echo "xfs_inode 1024 0 0" | sudo tee /proc/slabinfo
xfs_inode 1024 0 0
tee: /proc/slabinfo: Input/output error
```

What is the problem? Are there any way to limit the number of object in slab cache?

Comment: What manual is this?

Comment: Man page of linux. man slabinfo.

Answer (score 1):

The `slabinfo(5)` page is unfortunately quite out of date. If I understand correctly, in a kernel that is configured to use the SLUB allocator (available since Linux 2.6.22, and nowadays the default kernel memory allocator), the `/proc/slabinfo` file is not writable. See the contrasting definitions of `slabinfo_write()` in the kernel source files `mm/slub.c` and `mm/slab.c`. In `mm/slub.c`, `slabinfo_write()` simply fails with the error `EIO`.

Edit: Just confirmed my understanding by compiling a kernel to use the SLAB allocator rather than the default SLUB allocator. In this case, the `/proc/slabinfo` is writable in the manner posed in the original question. With `CONFIG_SLUB`, the file is not writable, and the tunables display as 0.